# If in a string at some index there is a number and I want to store it another variable then why we do int n=str[i]-'0'?

Tags: c++

I tried without '0' and got error,Please explain it.

```
getline(cin,str);
int n=str[4]-'0';
```

Comment: The string has the digit's ascii value. Also, the ascii values for all digits are contiguous. So to convert from the ascii value to the digit value, you can subtract the ascii value of '0'.

Comment: The ASCII value of '0' is 48 and that of '9' is 57. Basically, any number (literal) you encounter is in between and hence the subtraction does the job.